# XLS to HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, xls

I've got multiple XLS documents that needs convert to HTML/PHP so that the result pages would be dynamical. XLS have about 18 - 20 pages and lot of cell merging and text wrapping. The main problem is with Excel saving to HTML. It will create a HTML document which size is about 9MB and thats not OK. Also if saving to HTML will not do correct row spans.
So if theres any method to convert XLS fully to HTML without loosing layout would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this link: http://paggard.com/projects/xls.reader/
Browse to the XLS file, and it will create the HTML for you.

Comment: It says that it can do row and col span, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)? You can read the XLS, fill the cells with dynamic data, and export to HTML. I've never used it myself, but looking at its features it seems it can do the job.